# c++/catch2: Automatic unit testing during build with dependencies

Tags: c++, unit-testing, makefile, build

I'd like to add a number of unit tests to several components of my project, and I'd like them to run automatically when I build the corresponding .cpp file from a Makefile to ensure that my code is running as expected before I run the code. However, some of my .cpp files depend on other .cpp files, and I'd like the tests to run in order up the dependency tree when files are changed. The code has this sort of structure, for reference:

```
// main.cpp

#include <file_1.hpp>
#include <file_2.hpp>

int main()
{
  // call functions from file_1, file_2
  return 0;
}
```

```
// file_1.cpp

#include <file_1.hpp>
#include <file_3.hpp>

// a whole bunch of functions that I'd like to unit test with Catch2
// each of these functions uses variables from file_3
```

```
// file_3.hpp

namespace foo
{
  // a whole bunch of global constants that need to be referenced throughout the program

  // This is necessary because each of the functions in file_1 uses ~15 of these variables
  // in each function call for one calculation, so passing them without global scope would be
  // a massive pain, and passing them via structs would also be annoying because I'd need a
  // separate struct for each function call
  extern const int a;
  extern const double b;
  ...
}
```

```
// file_3.cpp

#include <file_3.hpp>

namespace foo
{
  const int a = 5;
  const double b = 10.0;
  ...
}
```

Then, when the Makefile compiles file_1.cpp into file_1.o, I want it to run a program such as test_file_1.cpp that runs unit tests for file_1.cpp using Catch2, and I want it to automatically know which object files need to be linked during compilation so that the Makefile can create and run test_file_1.exe with no build errors, even if I modify its dependency tree at a later date.

Additionally, if possible, I'd also like it to run unit tests in the order of the dependency tree, so if I have the following two other files:

```
// file_2.cpp

#include <file_2.hpp>
#include <file_4.hpp>

// a bunch of functions that call other functions in file_4
```

```
// file_4.cpp

#include <file_4.hpp>

// a bunch of functions
```

Then test_file_4.exe would run before test_file_2.exe during the build process.

I can't seem to find any references on how to make Catch2 work with multiple files, and especially not automatically during build. Most of the things I've seen involves using Catch2 on a single file with no dependencies and with incredibly simple functions, such as the following:

```
#include <catch2/catch_test_macros.hpp>

#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN

unsigned int Factorial( unsigned int number ) {
    return number > 1 ? Factorial(number-1)*number : 1;
}

TEST_CASE( "Factorials are computed", "[factorial]" ) {
    REQUIRE( Factorial(0) == 1 );
    REQUIRE( Factorial(1) == 1 );
    REQUIRE( Factorial(2) == 2 );
    REQUIRE( Factorial(3) == 6 );
    REQUIRE( Factorial(10) == 3628800 );
}
```

This is helpful for me to see how unit testing with this would work on a single file in a function that doesn't use anything from any other functions or files, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to extend this to my case.

Comment: To solve we need the buildsystem. This has nothing to do with what Untitest framework you are using